# Div showing before slidedown when using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with a Div that is temporarily shown before, sliding into view.

The Div should be visible if no javascript is available and start hidden if javascript is available. I use css and javascript.

```
.no-js .show {
    display:block
}

$('body').removeClass('no-js').addClass('js-ok');
```

However, I want to slide the div in rather than just show it. Here's the code:

```
$('#site-cookie-notice').slideDown();
```

The result is that the div temporarily shows (via the css), before being hidden, then re-displayed with javascript.

Any ideas as to how this could be worked around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. Put the code that adds/removes the js class in the head
2. DO NOT put it inside a `$(document).ready()` like so many people do.
3. Put the classes of no-js and js-ok on your HTML, instead of your body (your body element won't be available when your code gets executed)

If you do it like this, then the classes will get applied to the HTML element before the rest of the page is rendered (meaning your `.no-js .show` CSS rule will never get applied).

Like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js></script>
  <script>
    $('html').removeClass('no-js').addClass('js-ok');
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   ...
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using doc.ready? You need to use blocking JS like Modernizr does to replace your `no-js` class in the head. That way it'll be hidden when it's first rendered. Modernizr does it in the `head` thus:

```
var docElement = document.documentElement;
docElement.className = docElement.className.replace('no-js', 'js-ok');
```

Comment: Modernizr doesn't specifically use "blocking JS" - it just is required to be a script tag in the head in order to work. All script tags are blocking (regardless of position), and if they are in the head then the rest of the page won't get rendered until the script is downloaded and executed.

Comment: The term blocking js makes total sense here, you could still asynchronously include a script in the head, or defer part of it's execution until later. The fact that we swap the class name, then proceed loading means the page will render in full correctly.